# C++ Biginteger, what does this mean?

Tags: c++

I am puzzled about why we need a BASE=100000000 and WIDTH=8. This code is from a book, but I don't understand it.

```
struct Biginteger {
  static const BASE = 100000000;
  static const WIDTH = 8;

  vector<int> s;
  Biginteger(long long int num = 0) { *this = num; }
  Biginteger operator=(long long num) {
    s.clear();
    do {
      s.push_back(num % BASE);
      num /= BASE;
    } while (mun > 0);
    return *this;
  }
```

Comment: You haven't demonstrated the use of `WIDTH`, which makes it impossible to deduce it's purpose. A reference, even just the title of the book would be helpful. Also, it's not clear what you aren't understanding? The specific values; how they're used; do you believe they're not needed at all?

Comment: Thank you very much.I got your points.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types is not able to store arbitrarily large numbers and this is why you need BigInteger here. The idea of BigInteger is to use sequence of small numbers in primitive types to represent a large number.

With `BASE=100000000` and `WIDTH=8`, you are actually separating the original number 8 digits by 8 digits.

For example `254325623456546` will be `(2543256, 23456546)`

You can simply change to other (BASE, WIDTH). For example, `BASE=10`, `WIDTH=1` means you are storing the number digit by digit. For instance, `254325623456546` will be `(2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6)`.

Comment: I suggest pointing out the limitation of primitive types not being able to store arbitrarily large numbers in order to give your answer some context.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I have understand this problem further.